# Converting NSEnum from Userinfo in NSNotification fails in Objective c

Tags: c++, objective-c, swift, enums

I want to convert userInfo data from a NSNotification to an enum to use in a switch statement.  The notification is coming from a pre-compiled c++ framework with some headerfiles defining te enum.

```
-(void)updateOTAStatus:(NSNotification *)notification {
  NSDictionary *userInfo = notification.userInfo;
  otaUpgradeStatus status = (otaUpgradeStatus)userInfo[@"status"];
  //...
}
```

Enum definition:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, otaUpgradeStatus) {
  none = 0,
  started = 1,
  inProgress = 2,
  completed = 3,
  failed = 4,
  failedLowBattery = 5,
  cancelled = 6,
  timedout = 7,
  forced = 8
};
```

When debugging I get

```
Printing description of status:
(otaUpgradeStatus) status = 6178538944
```

And switch statement fails, when I do the same in Swift:

```
let status = notification.userInfo?["status"] as? otaUpgradeStatus
```

I get the right status back, and switch statement works as expected.

What goes wrong here?

Comment: My guess would be that the status is stored as an `NSNumber` in the dictionary. Try `NSNumber *num = userInfo[@"status"]; NSInteger status = num.integerValue;`

Comment: then I get -[_SwiftValue integerValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x174452420, this is probably because Notification is triggered from swift, goes to c++ library then to objective c module. I can see this in the stacktrace.

Comment: Do you create the notification? In that case it should help to add the status as an `NSNumber` to the info dictionary.

Comment: Something like `userInfo: ["status":  NSNumber(value: otaUpgradeStatus.failed.rawValue)]`

Comment: oh god thanks! Works!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An `NSDictionary` can only hold *objects,* i.e. instances of (a subclass of) `NSObject`. Swift has a mechanism to wrap/unwrap values in an
opaque `_SwiftValue` instance transparently.

But for interoperability with Objective-C you have to put the number
as `NSNumber` instances into the user info dictionary on the Swift side, e.g.

```
let notification = Notification(name: ..., object: ...,
         userInfo: ["status":  NSNumber(value: otaUpgradeStatus.failed.rawValue)])
```

and extract the integer value on the Objective-C side, e.g.

```
NSDictionary *userInfo = notification.userInfo;
NSNumber *num = userInfo[@"status"];
otaUpgradeStatus status = num.unsignedIntegerValue;
```